# melt multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, melt

Suppose I have the following dataframe:
[image]

What I want is process the dataframe to the following form:

[image]

I tried pd.melt function but unfortunately it just does really poor job with multiple columns melting. Any idea please?

Regards

Comment: Do you always have the same values in all the columns for the same row?

Comment: yes I have the same values in a given row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy all columns names to each row and last add new column `Qte`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('Date')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(df1.columns.values, df1.shape), index=df1.index)
df2 = df2.rename(columns=lambda x: 'Crit{}'.format(x+1)).assign(Qte=df1.iloc[:, -1])
print (df2)
        Crit1 Crit2 Crit3 Crit4  Qte
Date                                
2016-06    XX    YY    ZZ    FF  100
2016-07    XX    YY    ZZ    FF  300
2019-08    XX    YY    ZZ    FF  400
```

**Timings**:

```
N = 1000
a = np.random.randint(100, size=N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'FF':a, 'YY':a,'ZZ':a, 'XX':a}, index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=N, freq='M').to_period('M'))
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Date'})
print (df.head())
     Date  FF  XX  YY  ZZ
0 2000-01  49  49  49  49
1 2000-02  50  50  50  50
2 2000-03  72  72  72  72
3 2000-04  81  81  81  81
4 2000-05  29  29  29  29

In [165]: %%timeit
     ...: (df.set_index(['Date'])
     ...:   .stack()
     ...:   .reset_index(-1)
     ...:   .groupby('Date')
     ...:   .apply(lambda x: pd.concat([pd.Series(x.level_1.values),pd.Series(x[0].unique()[0])]))
     ...:   .set_axis(['Crit1','Crit2','Crit3','Crit4','Qte'],axis=1, inplace=False))
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 904 ms per loop

In [166]: %%timeit
     ...: df1 = df.set_index('Date')
     ...: pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(df1.columns.values, df1.shape), index=df1.index).rename(columns=lambda x: 'Crit{}'.format(x+1)).assign(Qte=df1.iloc[:, -1])
     ...: 
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.89 ms per loop
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks. I've learned a lot once again from you.

Comment: @ScottBoston - Thank you.